# How to print out square numbers like this?

Tags: python

i need output like this:

```
1 2 3 4 5
2 2 3 4 5
3 3 3 4 5 
4 4 4 4 5
5 5 5 5 5
```

this is what i can do but it's not right

```
size=int(input())
for row in range(1,size+1):
    for col in range(1,size+1):
        print(row,end=' ')
    print(col)
```

only use forloop

Answer (score 2):

You can do:

```
size = int(input())
for i in range(1, size+1):
    print(' '.join(str(max(i, j)) for j in range(1, size+1)))
```

Example for size of 9:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
2 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
3 3 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
4 4 4 4 5 6 7 8 9
5 5 5 5 5 6 7 8 9
6 6 6 6 6 6 7 8 9
7 7 7 7 7 7 7 8 9
8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 9
9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9
```

It however doesn't print nicely for double digits:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
2 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
3 3 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
4 4 4 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
5 5 5 5 5 6 7 8 9 10
6 6 6 6 6 6 7 8 9 10
7 7 7 7 7 7 7 8 9 10
8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 9 10
9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 10
10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10
```

So you can find the number of digits, and pad the strings:

```
import math

max_n = 10
digits = int(math.log10(max_n))+1
for i in range(1, max_n+1):
    print(' '.join(str(max(i, j)).rjust(digits) for j in range(1, max_n+1)))


 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
 2  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
 3  3  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
 4  4  4  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
 5  5  5  5  5  6  7  8  9 10
 6  6  6  6  6  6  7  8  9 10
 7  7  7  7  7  7  7  8  9 10
 8  8  8  8  8  8  8  8  9 10
 9  9  9  9  9  9  9  9  9 10
10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10
```

Answer (score 0):

Single loop:

```
size=int(input())

for i in range(1, size + 1):    
    print(' '.join([str(max([i, j])) for j in range(1, size + 1)]))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an easy to understand example :

```py
num = int(input("Input a number : "))

for i in range(1, num+1):
    row = ""
    for j in range(1, num+1):
        row += " " + str(j if j > i else i)
    print(row)
```

Answer (score 0):

I make a list for each row. If the row number is `i` then the row starts with `i` i's. After that it counts up to the given size.

```
size = int(input())

for row in range(1, size + 1):
    lst = [row] * row + list(range(row + 1, size + 1))
    print(' '.join([str(i) for i in lst]))
```

Output for `size = 5`:

```
1 2 3 4 5
2 2 3 4 5
3 3 3 4 5
4 4 4 4 5
5 5 5 5 5
```

Answer (score 0):

A solution following your code's logic:

```
for row in range(1,size+1):
    cnt = 1
    for col in range(1,size+1):
       if(cnt < row):
           printNum = row
    else:
        printNum = cnt
    cnt = cnt + 1
    if(printNum > 9):
        print(printNum,end=' ')
    else:
        print(printNum,end='  ')
    print("\n")
```

Answer (score 0):

Yet another variation:

```
size = input()
width = len(size)
size = int(size)+1
for i in range(1, size):
    print(*(f'{max(i, j):>{width}}' for j in range(1, size)))
```

Answer (score 0):

This does it:

```
size=int(input())

for col in range(1,size+1):
    for row in range(1,size+1):
        if row <= col:
            print(col, end=' ')
        else:
            print(row, end=' ')
    print()
```

It's not the most elegant answer but it works for any size.

Answer (score 0):

Walrus to rescue. For Python 3.8+

```
(size := int(input("Input a number : ")) + 1)
for i in range(1, size):
    print(' '.join(str(max(i, j)) for j in range(1, size)))
```

Result:

```
Enter a number : 5
1 2 3 4 5
2 2 3 4 5
3 3 3 4 5
4 4 4 4 5
5 5 5 5 5
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    # write a program to traverse every element of the two-dimensional array in Python.  
dt = [ [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [2, 2, 3, 4, 5], [3, 3, 3, 4, 5 ], [4, 4, 4, 4, 5], [5, 5, 5, 5, 5] ]  
# Use for loop to print the entire elements of the two dimensional array.  
for x in dt:  # outer loop  
    for i in x:  # inner loop  
        print(i, end = " ") # print the elements  
    print()
```

This code will give you output like this:

```
1 2 3 4 5 
2 2 3 4 5 
3 3 3 4 5 
4 4 4 4 5 
5 5 5 5 5
```

but you have to input the array manually